# How to do sequential subscription in Meteor(iron:router)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

For example, I have to something like this:

```
Router.route('/threadList', {
waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('threads', Meteor.userId);
},
data: function() {
    threads = Threads.find();
    _.each(threads, function(thread) {
        _.each(thread.comments, function(commentId) {
            Meteor.subscribe('comments', commentId);
       })
   })
}
```

I dont know how to do this kind of thing in Meteor

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more efficient to have the subscription take an array of comment ids instead of a single id? Then you could build up the array and subscribe only once.

Comment: this question comes up all the time and there are multiple answers on stackoverflow already. You can also read this: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check out the package [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite)

to do reactive joins in your publication code.

just add it to your project: `meteor add reywood:publish-composite`

then do your publish like so:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('publishName', { 
    find: function() {
        return Threads.find({userId: this.userId});
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(thread) {
                 return Comments.find({threadId: thread._id});
            }
        }
});
```